# Unzip password protected zip file with ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, zip

Being able to work with password-protected ZIP files was apparently added in ColdFusion 11. Yippee!

However, I'm currently stuck on ColdFusion 9 (and there's nothing I can do to move to a more recent version).

How can I unzip a `zip` file with a password in ColdFusion 9?

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong. CFZip did not support passwords until CF11. So here are a couple of other suggestions:

1. Drop down to Java and use a java function / library to do this.
2. Use [`cfexecute`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfexecute) to drop to the command line and use a command line version of a zip program to zip / password protect the file. http://www.7-zip.org/ has a nice command line tool.

Comment: Is Java a viable solution? I am using version 1.6.0_29.

Comment: Sure. Do a search on [java unzip password](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[unzip][java]+password) and you will find a few suggestions on libraries. The `zip4j` example looks pretty simple. Give it a whirl. You could also download 11, take a peek in the `lib` directory and see which library CF uses internally.